# how to assign target id of jquery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having trouble understand jQuery ui tabs.

Basically, I want to click on a tab and have the data load outside of the #tabs div. How do I do that?

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true, active: false,
  beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
      ui.panel.html(
        "Error." );
    });
  }
});
});
```

html:

```
<div id="tabs"><ul><li><a href="datafile.php">Data</a></li></ul></div>
<div id="outsidediv">load data here</div>
```

Right now, it's loading data inside #tabs and I can't seem to find any info on how to change the target. Am I right in understanding that `panel` is what I want to set? And if so, how do I set it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
$('#outsidediv').html(/* data here*/);
```

inside the beforeLoad function.
Hope that helps.

Comment: what would I put for the `/*data here*/` part?